# prove by induction that $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n} - 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, induction

**Please explain how to solve the problem.** Here's what I have done.
Prove by induction the following inequality

$1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n} - 1$

1. Base case. For n = 1, we have 1=1
2. Induction hypothesis. Assume for $n = k$ the inequality is true
3. Inductive step. Prove for $n = k+1$  the inequality is true

$1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{n+1} - 1$

Now I'm stuck. I think I may use the induction hypothesis but have no idea how to do it.
*By the way, all the solutions for similar problems that I've searched on the internet were either too complicated or not using induction.*

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} &\le 2\sqrt n-1+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\\&<2\sqrt{n+1}- 1\end{align}$$

since
$$2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)=\frac 2{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}>\frac1{\sqrt {n+1}}$$

giving

$$2\sqrt n+\frac1{\sqrt {n+1}}<2\sqrt{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1} {\sqrt{n+1}} \leq 2 \sqrt{n} -1 + \frac{1} {\sqrt{n+1}}.$$

Note that $$\frac{1} {\sqrt{n+1}} = 2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}).$$

Now you get $$2 \sqrt{n} -1 + \frac{1} {\sqrt{n+1}} = \sqrt{n} -1 + 2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}) = 2\sqrt{n+1}-1$$
as desire.